# PostgreSQL DB Design IF column is NULL then COALESCE(COLUMN A, COLUMN B)

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I'm designing a PostgreSQL schema and I want to create a rule that if the user doesn't enter a value for Column C then i make the value of column C COALESCE(COLUMN A, COLUMN B). 
I've tried table update, and a trigger but there must be something wrong with the logic, I'd appreciate your help - thanks.

I have tried:

1.

```
update Mytable 
    set ColC=
    case when ColC is NULL then COALESCE(ColA,ColB)
    else ColC;
```

2.

```
CREATE TRIGGER ColC_VIOLATION
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OF ColC
ON Mytable FOR EACH ROW
WHEN ColC is NULL then COALESCE(ColA,ColB)
```

3.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ColC_func() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
UPDATE Mytable
    set ColC=
    case when ColC is NULL then  COALESCE(ColA,ColB)
    else ColC ;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need an `UPDATE` statement in the trigger, just assign the value:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ColC_func() RETURNS trigger AS 
$$
BEGIN
   NEW.colc := COALESCE(NEW.cola, NEW.colb);
   RETURN NEW;
END
$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

And make the trigger only fire if `colc` is null:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ColC_VIOLATION
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE on mytable
  FOR EACH ROW execute procedure colc_func()
  WHEN ColC is NULL;
```